# how to compile mainline Linux-kernel with latest ICC and optimizations?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiler-optimization, icc

What are the source file which need to be modified in that case with intel compiler? How to use "-fast" or inter procedural optimizations if "-fast" is impossible?

edit:  forget this if it is too-specific: I use http://pf.natalenko.name and [ultra ksm](http://kerneldedup.org/projects/uksm/)

Comment: Linux relies very heavily on GCC extensions. I'd imagine you'd have a tough time getting it to compile on any other compiler (much less more optimized).

Comment: @tangrs : linuxdna maintained patches in the past that allowing compiling linux without wrappers. One problem is that it didn't allow optimizations, especially IPO ones. The project is dead and the latest patch goes with a kernel that didn't contain some drivers necessary for my PC unlike recent kernels which does.

Comment: [Similar question on Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17504/34451) for those who might be interested